# Finding Bryant Heatpump model

Tags: heat-pump

I am trying to find details about a heat pump model that a contractor provided me a quote for.

The specific model is

> Bryant Inverter heat pump 38MURAQAQ36B3 [High Heat]

I tried to google, bryant website as well as device report web site (https://device.report/BRYANT/38MURA)

But I am unable to find the specifications for this specific heat pump.
I am doing some research to make sure my purchase meets the energy tax credit requirements.

Can someone help me understand why it is so hard to find specific model numbers that the contractors quote?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a mistyped (possibly accidental, possibly deliberately) model number. In the [Bryant 38MURA Product Sheet](https://www.shareddocs.com/hvac/docs/1010/Public/0F/01-DLS-019-BR-01.pdf), I don't see a model 38MURAQAQ36B3 but I do see a 38MURAQ36AB3, and it is listed as "High Heat".

Plenty of details are listed. Not sure exactly what you need, but it lists:

- SEER 18.0
- EER 10.5
- SEER2 15.8
- EER2 9.8

and two sets of COP numbers depending on "M Rating" vs. "M1 Rating".

Comment: I did not mean that **you** mistyped. I mean the *contractor* mistyped - either accidentally (in a rush, "who cares if it is exact") or deliberately (harder to compare prices).

Comment: BTW, is the Bryant HeatPumps good. I am getting a quote of $12999 for the HP.

Comment: The link you put in a comment is the same I put in my answer.

Comment: Bryant is a good name. Is that particular product line "good"? I have no idea. Is the price appropriate? I have no idea. FYI, pricing is generally off topic here, because (a) it varies considerably over time (so it doesn't work for someone coming back and asking the same question 2 years from now), (b) it varies significantly by location (even for the same hardware, as I'm sure that $12,999 includes plenty of labor costs), (c) when it comes to complex systems such as HVAC, installations vary **a lot**. How much duct work? New thermostat and if so what type? Service contract? New electric

Comment: circuits needed? Etc. Too many variables. Maybe $13k is great. Maybe it is horrible. It may be hard (for a lot of reasons) to get the exact same unit quoted by multiple contractors. But see if you can get another contractor to quote a similar unit - i.e., similar SEER/EER/COP, 36,000 BTU, etc. It might come in within $1k of the first bid and then its a toss-up. Or it might be $8k or $17k. No idea.

Comment: Yes, sorry .. I gave the exact link as you did. Sorry, got too excited I guess :-(